# Multiple choice question about a sequence and sub-sequence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I was thinking about the following problem :

> Let $$f(x) = \begin{cases} \displaystyle \sin \frac{1}{x}, & x \neq 0, \\ 0, & x = 0. \end{cases}$$,where $x \in [-1,1]$

Then select the **incorrect** .

> 1. $\exists$ a sequence $\{a_n\}$ such that $\{a_n\} \to 0$ and $\{f(a_n)\}\to 0$
> 2. $\exists$ a sequence $\{a_n\}$ such that $\{a_n\} \to 0$ and $\{f(a_n)\}\to -1$
> 3. $\exists$ a sequence $\{a_n\}$ such that $\{a_n\} \to 0$ and $\{f(a_n)\}\to \frac12$
> 4. None of the above

Feel free to comment . Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: Imho it is okay.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to save this question from being unanswered and considering the comment made by @Peter Horvath, I am posting my answer  below:

If we take $a_n=1/nπ\quad$, then $a_n \to 0$ and  $f(a_n) = \sin nπ =0$ so option 1 is true, Now if $ \frac{1}{a_n} = nπ +(-1)^n 3π/2$,where $n$ is odd integer, then $ \{a_n\} \to 0,\,\,\{f(a_n)\} \to -1$ so option 2 is true, Further if we take $\frac{1}{a_n} =  {nπ +(-1)^n π/6}$ where $n$ is even , then $\{a_n\} \to 0,\,\,\{f(a_n)\} \to \frac12\,\,$ and so option 3 is also true. So option 4 is incorrect.